# Loading UIImage's on background thread solves SceneKit memory problems. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uiimage, scenekit

Consider the following code:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "myString")
if let img = img {
    mySCNMaterial.diffuse.contents = img    
}
```

I was using this to load images in a SceneKit project. Specifically, I was doing this from inside my `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`.

As long as I was doing it this way, my project was leaking memory like crazy (restarting a level in the game would bump memory consumption up by something like 30mb each time, and that memory would never be reclaimed). However, `Instruments` found no memory leaks, and enabling my project scheme's `Zombie Objects` gave results that were...literally unbelievable, with something like 1000+ zombies from all kinds of sources.

At some point, I learned about the difference between `UIImage(named:)` and `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`, with the system caching the former, but not the latter.

So, now I've got this:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myString", ofType: "png")!
let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)!
mySCNMaterial.diffuse.contents = img
```

I theorized that this would improve memory usage in my own game, but the gains were minimal at best.

But today I decided to try explicitly running the previous bit of code on a background thread (`UIImage` is thread-safe, according to the documentation) -- *and my game stopped leaking memory entirely*, as determined by the `Instruments` `Allocations` template.

So, now I've got this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myString", ofType: "png")!
    let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)!
    mySCNMaterial.diffuse.contents = img
}
```

While I'm very glad to have stumbled upon this fix, I'd like to better understand what's going on.

**Question:** Why might these changes solve my SceneKit game's memory usage problems?

Comment: Did you also try to call UIImage(named: "myString") trough the Background thread DispatchQueue? And if yes, stays it the same?

Comment: @ZAY I actually have NOT tried that. That would be a really good thing to try.