# 'IOSurface' memory keeps increasing in SceneKit project

Tags: ios, swift, memory, scenekit, iosurface

*This question is roughly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74713246/loading-uiimages-on-background-thread-solves-scenekit-memory-problems-why?).*

I have a SceneKit project in which memory management has been a challenge (yes, even with ARC).

By loading images in a very specific way, by using `weak` variables in closures, and by setting `SCNMaterial`s to `nil` prior to scene deallocation, I've been able to drastically improve the memory situation.

Here's how I'm loading the images:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak material] in
   let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myString", ofType: "png")!
   let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)

   material?.diffuse.contents = img
}
```

However, `Instruments` shows memory for category `VM: IOSurface` more or less continuously increasing without ever being adequately reclaimed. According to the documentation, `IOSurface` is related to image memory.

Here's what `Instruments` `Allocations` shows for `VM: IOSurface` (the memory here goes from about 17MB to about 69MB):
[image]

For the above graph, I loaded and then unloaded a SceneKit scene several times.

Here's a graph that illustrates how this `IOSurface` memory relates to the overall memory footprint:
[image]

And here are the callers of `IOSurface`:
[image]

Now, you might think I should use `UIImage(named:)` instead of `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`, as the system caches the former in memory but not the latter. But using the former resulted in *much* worse memory statistics in my project.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022559/iosurface-gradually-increases-memory-in-ios-12-and-above) on the matter, but it suggests that the problem is the device camera, which I'm not using.

**Question:** What can you tell me about how `IOSurface` relates to SceneKit, and how might I improve its memory usage?